# Integration by (further) substitution?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

**Question**

The function $f$ is defined on $[0, 1]$ by $$f(x) = e^{2\sqrt x}\ .$$

Use the substitution $x = u^2$ to find the exact area of the region enclosed by the graph of $f$, the axes and the line $x = 1$, then use your answer to deduce the exact value of $$\int_{1}^{e^2} (\ln y)^2\ \mathrm{d}y\ .$$

---

**My working**

Let the required area be $A$.

\begin{align}
A & =
\int_{0}^{1} e^{2\sqrt x}\ \mathrm{d}x
\\[5 mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1} 2ue^{2u}\ \mathrm{d}u
\end{align}

Let $s = 2u$ and $t' = e^{2u}\ .$

$\implies s' = 2$ and $t = \frac 1 2 e^{2u}\ .$

\begin{align}
A & =
[ue^{2u} - \frac 1 2 e^{2u}]^{u = 1}_{u = 0}
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac 1 2 (e^2 + 1)
\end{align}

---

I am able to complete the first part (finding the area), but I do not know how to proceed with the second part (evaluating the integral). I have tried to use another substitution, where $x = (\ln y)^2$, but I am not getting anywhere. Any help/intuition will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The second part is related to the integral of inverse functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions

Comment: @Player3236 So, my intuition is correct, that I should use the substitution $x = (\ln y)^2$?

Comment: Not exactly. The substitution will not work, but your intuition is related to the fact that these two functions in the integrals are *almost* inverses of each other, which helps out in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required integral is connected with the inverse function
$$y=e^{2 \sqrt{x}}\to 2\sqrt{x}=\ln y\to x=\frac{\ln^2 y}{4}$$
The area of the inverse function (red in the picture) is the area of the rectangle less the blue area calculated by OP.
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_1^{e^2}\ln^2 y\,dy=e^2-\frac{1+e^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^2-1\right)$$
Therefore requested integral is
$$\int_1^{e^2}\ln^2 y\,dy=2\left(e^2-1\right)$$

[image]

Comment: I managed to figure part of your answer out based on a hint given in the comments :) However, this question was given in a test and I doubt I would have been able to visualise the rectangle part. Is there any mathematical way to get the $e^2$ to "appear"?

Comment: @EthanMark For $x=1$ we have $y=e^2$